# How to fix 'Object of type xxx is not registered inside GetIt in flutter when the object is registered?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using get_it package for di in flutter and it gives me the following error:

> Invalid argument (Object of type EditProfileBloc is not registered
>   inside GetIt):

Comment: Show us some code if you want us to help you

Answer (score 0):

the problem is fixed. apparently there was a problem with registering another object YYY but somehow it showed me XXX in the error because it made use of YYY. if anyone is going through the problem just go through the objects you're registering and make sure it is correct!